# shell: send grep output to stderr and leave stdout intact

Tags: bash, redirect, sh, stdout, stderr

i have a program that outputs to `stdout` (actually it outputs to `stderr`, but i can easily redirect that to `stdout` with `2>&1` or the like.

i would like to run `grep` on the output of the program, and redirect all matches to `stderr` while leaving the unmatched lines on `stdout` (alternatively, i'd be happy with getting all lines - not just the unmatched ones - on `stdout`)

e.g.

```sh
$ myprogram() {
cat <<EOF
one line
a line with an error
another line
EOF
}
$ myprogram | greptostderr error >/dev/null
a line with an error
$ myprogram | greptostderr error 2>/dev/null
one line
another line
$
```

a trivial solution would be:

```sh
myprogram | tee logfile
grep error logfile 1>&2
rm logfile
```

however, i would rather get the matching lines on `stderr` when they occur, not when the program exits...

eventually, I found [this](https://www.unix.com/unix-for-advanced-and-expert-users/164110-how-set-font-color-stdin-stdout-stderr.html), which gave me a hint to for a a POSIX solution like so:

```sh
greptostderr() {
  while read LINE; do
    echo $LINE
    echo $LINE | grep -- "$@" 1>&2
  done
}
```

for whatever reasons, this does not output anything (probably a buffering problem).

a somewhat ugly solution that seems to work goes like this:

```
greptostderr() {
  while read LINE; do
    echo $LINE
    echo $LINE | grep -- "$@" | tee /dev/stderr >/dev/null
  done
}
```

are there any better ways to implement this?

ideally i'm looking for a POSIX shell solution, but `bash` is fine as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `awk` instead of `grep`, which gives you more flexibility in handling both matched and unmatched lines.

```
myprogram | awk -v p=error '{ print > ($0 ~ p ? "/dev/stderr" : "/dev/stdout")}'
```

Every line will be printed; the result of `$0 ~ p` determines whether the line is printed to standard error or standard output. (You may need to adjust the output file names based on your file system.)